# How to display on x-axis as percentages and how to display values (percent)?

Tags: r

To Sri Harsha Chilakapati and Efrem: here is the link,  how should look like graph - http://ulozto.cz/xcTuwHEG/graph-jpeg

I wanted to insert a graph directly and immediately, but it did not work.

Jirka

```
84
113
9
5
9
168
4
10

mollusca<-as.matrix(read.table("clipboard",head=F,row.names=1))

color<-c('chartreuse4', 'darkolivegreen2', 'darkkhaki', 'ghostwhite', 'Gold1',
            'darkgoldenrod4', 'cadetblue1', 'blue')

b<-barplot(mollusca,beside=F,horiz=T,main=NULL,sub=NULL,width=c(35),col=color,ylim=c(0,max(mollusca+20)),ylab=NULL,xlab="Cumulative percentage",border=NULL)

legend("top", c("přísně lesní druhy","lesní druhy vyskytující se i mimo les","silně vlhkomilné lesní druhy","silvifóbní druhy otevřených stanovišť","termofilní a xerotolerantní druhy","druhy se středními nároky","vlhkomilné druhy,nevázané přímo na mokřady","vodní druhy")
       , cex=0.8, fill=color,ncol=2,bty="n")
```

Comment: You also need to explain what you are having, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Let's see a reproducible example. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) are a few tips on how to proceed.

Comment: Could you provide an example of output?